# Bandpass filters using capacitively coupled series resonators

Tags: filter, microwave, band-pass

I was wondering how to decide on the gap size for capacitances. Here is the figure from Microwave Engineering by Pozar:

[image]

I can calculate the B values, θs and other related stuff. Furthermore, I can simulate circuit (b) from the figure.

However, I want to see (a) in the simulation, but couldn't find an equation for converting capacitors into gaps.